# Change Font on HTML/CSS for Medium Widget

Tags: html, css, web, colors, fonts

I'm completely new to coding and I just used [Pixelpoint's](https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/) tool for generating a widget to display my medium articles on my website. However, the font of the widget (titles, descriptions, names etc.) all seems to be in Times New Roman. Is there any way to change this to Arial? The code that I generated is:

```
<div id="medium-widget"></div>
    <script src="https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/widget.js"></script>
    <script>MediumWidget.Init({renderTo: '#medium-widget', params: {"resource":"https://medium.com/@redacted","postsPerLine":1,"limit":10,"picture":"small","fields":["description","author","claps","publishAt"],"ratio":"landscape"}})</script>
```

Also, there seems to be a horizontal scroll bar on this widget after I import it to my Google Sites website. How do I get rid of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="medium-widget" style="font-family: Arial"></div>
    <script src="https://medium-widget.pixelpoint.io/widget.js"></script>
    <script>MediumWidget.Init({renderTo: '#medium-widget', params: {"resource":"https://medium.com/@redacted","postsPerLine":1,"limit":10,"picture":"small","fields":["description","author","claps","publishAt"],"ratio":"landscape"}})</script>
```